# Taking a screenshot in Windows will output a black screen image

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi+

I'm trying to take a full page screenshot in windows. function works in first call but after second call won't work at all and it's just getting a black screen image with a stable size.
when i use debugger the function works well without giving the black screen.

Here is the code:

```
void screenshot(std::string imageaPath)
{
    ULONG_PTR gdiplustoken;
    Gdiplus::GdiplusStartupInput gdistartupinput;
    Gdiplus::GdiplusStartupOutput gdistartupoutput;

    gdistartupinput.SuppressBackgroundThread = true;
    GdiplusStartup(&gdiplustoken, &gdistartupinput, &gdistartupoutput); //start GDI+

    HDC hScreenDC = GetDC(GetDesktopWindow());
    HDC hMemoryDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hScreenDC);

    int cx = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXVIRTUALSCREEN);
    int cy = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYVIRTUALSCREEN);
    int x = GetSystemMetrics(SM_XVIRTUALSCREEN); 
    int y = GetSystemMetrics(SM_YVIRTUALSCREEN);

    HBITMAP hbitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hScreenDC, cx, cy);
    HBITMAP holdbitmap = static_cast<HBITMAP>(SelectObject(hMemoryDC, hbitmap));

    BitBlt(hMemoryDC, 0, 0, cx, cy, hScreenDC, x, y, SRCCOPY | CAPTUREBLT);
    hbitmap = static_cast<HBITMAP>(SelectObject(hMemoryDC, holdbitmap));    

    UINT num, size;

    Gdiplus::ImageCodecInfo* imagecodecinfo;
    Gdiplus::GetImageEncodersSize(&num, &size); // get count of codec

    imagecodecinfo = (Gdiplus::ImageCodecInfo*)(malloc(size));
    GetImageEncoders(num, size, imagecodecinfo);//get codec

    CLSID clsidEncoder;

    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        if (wcscmp(imagecodecinfo[i].MimeType, L"image/jpeg") == 0)
            clsidEncoder = imagecodecinfo[i].Clsid; // get jpeg codec id
    }

    free(imagecodecinfo);
    Gdiplus::Bitmap* bm = new Gdiplus::Bitmap(hbitmap, NULL);
    std::wstring ws;
    ws.assign(imageaPath.begin(), imageaPath.end());//sring to wstring
    bm->Save(ws.c_str(), &clsidEncoder); //save in jpeg format
    SelectObject(hMemoryDC, holdbitmap);//Release Objects
    DeleteObject(hMemoryDC);
    DeleteObject(hbitmap);
    ReleaseDC(GetDesktopWindow(), hScreenDC);

    Gdiplus::GdiplusShutdown(gdiplustoken);
}
```

update:

Okay i find a way to take a screenshot without black screen image
when i use `system("pause");` to make program stop and when press enter to make program continue, it's working, I used c++ sleep methods but not works, any idea?

```
...
HBITMAP holdbitmap = static_cast<HBITMAP>(SelectObject(hMemoryDC, hbitmap));

system("pause");

BitBlt(hMemoryDC, 0, 0, cx, cy, hScreenDC, x, y, SRCCOPY | CAPTUREBLT);
...
```

sleep methods:

```
Sleep(1000);
std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
```

update 2:

I was sending screenshot request using curl and I was testing in a server(rdp) and I was logged out when i was sending request, I think sleep mode in server is enabled and when I logged out the server will be sleep and it's like computer screen to go dark and that's why BitBlt() fails and GetLastError() will return 5 which means access denied

Comment: Is it necessary to start and destroy GDI+ every time if you're going to call this function multiple times?

Comment: You're calling `SelectObject(hMemoryDC, holdbitmap);` twice (not really a problem, just useless).

Comment: I don't think you can call `GdiplusShutdown` while a `Bitmap` object still exists.  You should destroy `bm` properly.  Or just allocate it on the stack in a local scope.

Comment: Note related to your problem, but `assign()` is the wrong way to convert a `std::string` to a `std::wstring`. Either take a `std::wstring` to begin with, or else use `std::wstring_convert` or `MultiByteToWideChar()` or equivalent to convert `char` data to `wchar_t` data.

Comment: Where's the error checking code?

Comment: @David Heffernan BitBlt() fails in second call. GetLasrError() will return 5, which means Access is denied I think, but why?

Comment: I don't know. You really should post a [mcve] with full error checking

Comment: @David Heffernan thank you so much for saying that, I created a loop for screenshots in main function and works well and the problem is in my class thanks!

Comment: im using curl to send screenshot request, when I call curl BitBlt() fails, I tried to use a thread in main to take screenshot every 3 sec but it also fails when curl functions will be called and this time GetLastError() will return 6

Answer (score 6):

[The documentation for `GdiplusShutdown`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/gdiplusinit/nf-gdiplusinit-gdiplusshutdown) says that

> You must call `GdiplusStartup` before you create any GDI+ objects, and **you must delete all of your GDI+ objects** (or have them go out of scope) **before you call `GdiplusShutdown`**.

You are leaking `bm = new Gdiplus::Bitmap(...)` which is violating this rule.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, I fixed the code to clean bm ( Bitmap object ) before GdiplusShutdown but still I'm getting thr black screen image, how to solve this?

Answer (score -1):

you can use [PrintWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-printwindow) to replace BitBlt api, the `nFlags` of PrintWindow should set to be `PW_RENDERFULLCONTENT`, make sure you called this on a windows 8.1 and later os computer, it may be works, just have a try.